# Existence of encryption schemes where $F_{k}^{-1} \big( F_{k}(A) + R \big) = A + O(R)$

Tags: encryption, reference-request

Is there a encryption scheme in literature, where I can do something like

$$F_{k_1}^{-1} \big( F_{k_2}(A) + R \big) = A + O(R)$$

where, $A$ is a $m \times n$ real matrix,  $R$ is a $m \times n$ real matrix that contains some random noise, and (preferably, $k_1 \neq k_2$)

essentially what I want is a scheme where if the encryption of my matrix $A$ 'picks up' *some*  noise, the decryption should not be heavily effected, and the noise after the decryption is of order $O(R)$

---

EDIT: Since there has been no concrete answers yet, let's relax the the $k$s.. what if we are willing to have $k_1 = k_2$?

Comment: In other words, decryption should be [Lipschitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity)? $\;$

Comment: I am not too sure I understood what it meant, but can there be a Lipschitz function for an encryption scheme in the first place?

Comment: Oh, I see that my comment would only have been right if the keys were the same _and_ the expression was supposed to work for all $R$. $\;$

Comment: I would suggest **lattice encryption** because it's based on addition. check out this scheme: [[BrVa11]](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~vinodv/BV-Crypto2011.pdf) (go section 1.1, "the basic scheme"). It's just a trail, not sure this one works because it seems if you add $r$ you decrypt to $m+r\bmod2$ but because of short vector problem you can have troubles relating it to $m$.

Comment: Following the suggestion of Cédric Van Rompay, there is probably a connexion with the general Lattice problems. I recommand you to dig the construction of Ajtai-Dwork cryptoSystem, which present in my sense some similarities with your problem. Cf also the attack of Phong & J. Stern here: http://antoanthongtin.vn/Portals/0/UploadImages/kiennt2/KyYeu/DuLieuNuocNgoai/3.Advances%20in%20cryptology-Crypto%201998-LNCS%201462/14620223.PDF